How does Newton's Cradle work in terms of the Newtonian forces?
Imagine there's two spheres X and Y. why does X completely decelerate when Y applies an equal and opposite force? Also when X applies a force on Y why doesn't Y immediately move? Why does it exert a force on X first?
Also is Newton's 1st law involved? if yes, then how?


why does X completely decelerate when Y applies an equal and opposite force?

Both momentum conservation and energy conservation must hold. If the spheres have equal masses, momentum conservation gives:
$$v_{X1} = v_{X2} + v_{Y2},$$
and energy conservation gives:
$$v_{X1}^2 = v_{X2}^2 + v_{Y2}^2.$$
Combining these, we find:
$$(v_{X2} + v_{Y2})^2 = v_{X2}^2 + v_{Y2}^2 + 2v_{X2}v_{Y2}=v_{X2}^2 + v_{Y2}^2 .$$
This is only true if $2v_{X2}v_{Y2} = 0$, meaning either $v_{X2} = 0$ or $v_{Y2} = 0$. Since $Y$ does not remain still, $v_{X2} = 0$. Thus, $X$ stops entirely due to the force from $Y$.

when X applies a force on Y why doesn't Y immediately move? Why does it exert a force on X first?

Force causes acceleration, not immediate speed. When $X$ hits $Y$, $Y$ experiences an unbalanced force, causing acceleration ($\sum F = ma$). However, it takes a small but non-zero amount of time for this acceleration to significantly increase $Y$’s speed. During this time, $X$ pushes $Y$, and $Y$ pushes back on $X$, decelerating $X$ to rest.

is Newton's 1st law involved? if yes, then how?

No. Newton’s 1st law states that balanced forces result in no acceleration ($\sum F = 0$). This does not apply during the impact, as the forces are unbalanced. It is only relevant for vertical forces in this context (e.g., gravity and the normal force from the table and the like), which do not influence the horizontal collision.

The simplest (and admittedly unrealistic) approach to colliding spheres in Newtonian mechanics is to assume that the spheres have exactly equal masses, are perfectly rigid, and that the collision is perfectly elastic.
With these assumptions, if one sphere (X) initially has velocity $v$ and the other sphere (Y) is initially at rest, then conservation of kinetic energy (since the collision is perfectly elastic) and conservation of momentum (which always applies) tell us that after the collision sphere X is at rest and sphere Y has velocity $v$. The initial momentum of sphere $X$ is transferred to sphere $Y$ in a single instant of time.
If we examine the collision itself then the unrealistic nature of these assumptions becomes apparent. Because the spheres are perfectly rigid the collision is instantaneous - it takes a single instant in time. To accelerate sphere $Y$ from rest to speed $v$ in one instant means that $X$ must apply an "infinite" force to $Y$ for this infinitesimal instant of time. And by Newton's Third Law, $Y$ also applies an "infinite" force to $X$ for an infinitesimal instant of time, instantly decelerating $X$ from speed $v$ to rest.
To make the collision itself more realistic we must change our assumptions and allow both spheres to deform by a small amount during the collision, and then regain their original shape. Now the collision takes some small but finite amount of time, the forces involved are large but finite, and the rates of acceleration of $Y$ and deceleration of $X$ are again large but finite. You could in principle use Newton's First Law to relate the force required to deform each sphere to the rate of acceleration of deceleration of that sphere. Also, no collision in real life is perfectly elastic, so some small amount of energy is dissipated into the environment (as heat and sound) in each collision, which is why Newton's cradle eventually stops.
If the spheres are, for example, solid metal balls and $v$ is not too fast then the simple unrealistic model gives a solution after the collision that is close enough to reality for most purposes - and we are not usually looking too closely at what happens during the collision itself. So often we just use the simple model and ignore its unrealistic aspects.

Forces transfer momentum over time ( $ \vec{F}=d\vec{p}/dt $ )
The spheres cannot generate infinite force, so the collision must take some short amount of time.
During the collision, energy is stored in the spring-like elastic deformation of the spheres.
The springs return ( almost all ) the energy to the spheres, finalizing the collision.
Consider the situation where a single sphere, with momentum $m\vec{v}$ and energy $mv^2/2$ collides
with the other four.
During the collision, the sum of kinetic energy plus spring potential energy will remain constant.
The forces of the collision negotiate a solution which preserves total energy and momentum.
The solution cannot be that the momentum and energy is divided evenly between two balls. If momentum
is divided between two balls, then velocity is halved. If velocity is halved, then each ball would have
energy $(m(v/2)^2)/2= mv^2/8$, so total energy for both spheres would be $mv^2/4$ (not conserved).
Dividing the momentum between multiple balls in other fashions also fail to satisfy.
The mechanics of the cradle prevent motion at an angle to the center line, so the only conserving solution
the system can reach is to give all the energy and momentum to a single ball on the other side. When the
springs all return their energy, that is where it ends up.
